# maskMoney sem precisar de selecionar o input

Tags: jquery, maskmoney

Galera estou usando o maskMoney porém ele so formata valor se eu clicar no input, tem como alterar isso? Ou seja para ele formatar assim que a página for carregada?

```js
$(function() {

  $("input").maskMoney({
    allowNegative: true,
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ',',
    affixesStay: false
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="-90.00"/>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

você pode forçar a formatação ao disparar o evento `mask.maskMoney`.

```js
$(function() {
  var maxLength = '-0.000.000,00'.length;
  
  $("input").maskMoney({
    allowNegative: true,
    thousands: '.',
    decimal: ',',
    affixesStay: false
  }).attr('maxlength', maxLength).trigger('mask.maskMoney');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-maskmoney/3.0.2/jquery.maskMoney.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="-90.00"/>
```

Comment: muito bom, funcionou 100%. Me tira só mais uma dúvida, como limito o numero máximo para 0.000.000,000?

Comment: @HugoBorges, não sei se é possível através da `API` do `maskMoney`, mas tente setar um `maxlength` para o `input`

Comment: editei a resposta, não fica 100%, mas já é um começo.

Comment: ficou muito bom isso ai :)